# rails link_to with block, controller options and html post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, link-to

I am trying to use **link_to** in **rails 4** with controller and html options and a **do..end block.** I have seen similar posts but have not been able to use any of the answers successfully.

**Working code without a do..end block:**

```
<%= link_to 'recommend', { controller: 'recommendations', id: offer.id }, method: :post %>
```

**When I try to use some embedded ruby to add extra information to the link, I cannot get it to work:**

```
<%= link_to( { controller: 'recommendations', id: offer.id }, method: :post) do %>
  <p>Some Html</p><%= offer.recommendations %>
<% end %>
```

The code compiles but in the rendered, the link that is generated is the following:

```
<a controller="recommendations" id="38">
  <p>Some Html</p>0
</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I think that it is a small problem with the syntax but I have tried all manner of brackets, spaces etc that I could think of without luck.

**UPDATE:** I have tried the following code without success:

```
<%= link_to( { controller: 'recommendations', action: 'create', id: offer.id }, method: :post) do %>
  <p>Some Html</p><%= offer.recommendations %>
<% end %>
```

The HTML output is:

```
<a action="create" controller="recommendations" id="39">
  <p>Some Html</p>0
</a>
```

This might not be important but as a side note, the create action doesn't have a helper function for links. When I run the

```
rake routes
```

command I get the following

```
...
recommendations GET     /recommendations(.:format)     recommendations#index
                POST    /recommendations(.:format)     recommendations#create
new_recommendation GET  /recommendations/new(.:format) recommendations#new
...
```

In my opinion this isn't a problem but it is a reason why code such as:

```
link_to create_recommendation_path
```

won't work. Finally, the intention of the link is to act as a 'like' button. It creates a recommendation and then displays the current page again. Once again, thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `link_to create_recommendation_path` doesn't work is because there is no named route for `create_recommendation_path`, only for `recommendations_path`.  You can see the named routes in your routes list (which you have in your post above).  The left most column that comes out of routes shows the named routes.  Notice that `recommendations#create` doesn't have an entry in the list.

You could probably get the path you want with

```
<%= link_to recommendations_path(:offer_id => offer.id), :method => :post do %>
    html stuff
<% end %>
```

This should post to a path that looks like

```
/recommendations?offer_id=<the offer id>
```

(except the post data will be in the headers not on the URL)
This will work if the `create` method going to do something like

```
Recommendation.create(params)
```

and the only parameter you need to create a new Recommendation is an `offer_id`

What I don't understand is why you're trying to POST with a link?  Does creating a recommendation only require an offer id?

Comment: This solution works with the minor modification of changing the hash key offer_id to id to match my controller. The recommendation requires just the offer_id and the authenticated user's id so posting with a link suffices. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your `link_to` you're only specifying a controller, you need to also specify the action otherwise it doesn't know where to route it to. Either use:

```
<%= link_to({ controller: 'recommendations', action: 'show', id: offer.id }) do %>
  <p>Some Html</p><%= offer.recommendations %>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to({ show_recommendations_path(id: offer.id) }) do %>
  <p>Some Html</p><%= offer.recommendations %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In my original post, the first link (without the code block) works fine without an action. When I add the 'create' action using the hash method (the first one in your answer), I get the following HTML output and a non-functional link:
`<a action="create" controller="recommendations" id="39">
     <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> (0)
</a>` I'll add more details to the original post.